# BeautifulSoup extract contents from rows and cols from table but I am getting only one td out

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract some data from my Selenium Test Report html file.  I am getting only 1 value out from one td column from the table.
I would like to iterate over the table and print out the values from the rows and columns.

My HTML snippet is:

```
<table id='result_table'>
<colgroup>
<col align='left' />
<col align='right' />
<col align='right' />
<col align='right' />
<col align='right' />
<col align='right' />
</colgroup>
<tr id='header_row'>
    <td>Test Group/Test case</td>
    <td>Count</td>
    <td>Pass</td>
    <td>Fail</td>
    <td>Error</td>
    <td>View</td>
</tr>

<tr class='passClass'>
    <td>Regression_TestCase.RegressionProjectEdit_TestCase.RegressionProject_TestCase_Project_Edit</td>
    <td>75</td>
    <td>75</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td><a href="javascript:showClassDetail('c1',75)">Detail</a></td>
</tr>
```

My desired output format would be:

```
Count   Pass    Fail    Error   
75      75      0       0
```

My code is:

```
table = soup.find('table', {'id': 'result_table'})
tr = table.find('tr', {'id': 'header_row'})
td = tr.findNext('td')
for item in td:
    print td, "\t",
print "\n"
```

The output I am getting is:

```
<td>Test Group/Test case</td>
```

How can I get my desired output please?

Thanks, Riaz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the table by id, then extract the rows and find the td tags slicing the second to second last:

```
   In [40]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    
   In [41]: soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")  
   # can use .find(id="result_table")  
   In [42]: table = soup.select_one("#result_table")  


   In [45]: for row in table.find_all("tr"):
      ....:     print(" ".join([td.text for td in row.find_all("td")[1:-1]]))
      ....:     
   Count Pass Fail Error  
   75 75 0 0
```

`table.find('tr', {'id': 'header_row'})` would only select the first tr in your example, then `tr.findNext('td')` would only get the first td after the *header_row* *tr* so that is why you only see *Test Group/Test case*.

Another approach is to use the class name for the *tr's*, presuming all the interesting rows have that class:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
table = soup.select_one("#result_table")
headers= [td.text for td in table.select_one("#header_row").find_all("td")[1:-1]]
print(" ".join(headers))
for row in table.select("tr.passClass"):
    print(" ".join([td.text for td in row.find_all("td")[1:-1]]))
```

Comment: Tanks, this does work.  I am getting the output  Count Pass Fail Error 75 75 0 0 but then I am getting a few blank rows and then the output 75 75 0 0 again.

Comment: @RiazLadhani, can you share the actual html, most likely there are breaks in the tables where there are no tds, you can of course use `tds = row.find_all("td")[1:-1]` `if tds ...` but maybe we can be more specific, do all data rows with tds have the class *passClass*?

Comment: Your second approach works fine.  I will use that.  Thanks very much for your help.